# Iphone emulator

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create an iphone emulator just to take a screenshot of web page and know how are rendered.

My first attempt is to try with integrated air webkit.

I've tried also with phantomjs but the creator said that is not well suitable with this kind of purpose.

So I wanna know if there is a way to create an emulator to take a screenshot of iphone with some tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), it has a very good Emulator/Simulator.
And it will support all known screen sizes.

You can also try this (it's web based)
http://testiphone.com/
not a good one but the browser does it all.No need of simulators;-)

And other possibility is [this](http://www.iemu.org/index.php/Main_Page), but i never did try it.

Comment: @H2CO3 in this case — where the objective is strictly just to emulate the Mobile Safari visual output and not any other characteristics of an iPhone — you could probably argue it. With emulation where's always got to be some level at which you say 'which actor am I trying to fool?'

Comment: I would like to implement a web service based on linux. If I understand well, this emulator on xcode runs only in mac osx environment...this is my problem.

Comment: Another question is: if I decide to use a Xcode emulator, can I run this from command line and take screenshot of web page?