# Is there an iPhone emulator that mimics User-Agent strings so I can use php-mobile-detect?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, mobile

Is there a website or application which can entirely emulate an iPhone? All of the ones that I’ve tried…

- http://www.testiphone.com/
- http://ipadpeek.com/
- http://iphonetester.com/

…replicate the look of a web page on an iPhone in terms of CSS `media` queries, but [php-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) still performs as though I am accessing the page via my desktop. This makes it impossible for me to load separate scripts for a mobile device.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634178/iphone-emulator), I’ve downloaded Xcode. But I don’t understand how to use it to load a web page with an emulated iPhone.

Comment: Here is the doc for the simulator: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

Comment: If you are using Firefox then you might install this plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/ it will allow you to modify the header so you can send the header php mobile detect is expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is not. Some will argue that there are simulators that utilize the iOS kernal but they are sadly mistaken. Emulation for iOS can ONLY be done through the device itself or xCode on an Apple platform.

"With iOS Simulator you can simulate **most** of the actions a user performs on a device."
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

Comment: Yeah, iOS simulator ignores the media-queries that the online emulators handle correctly.

Comment: @thomas Online emulators may emulate media queries correctly but do not understand rotaion events and native bindings. Key in front end development.

Comment: Okay. Both features seem key to me. Sort of incredible that there isn't an application that does media queries and mobile events. Guess I'll just have to get an iPhone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have tried our application with [Google chrome's Mobile emulation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation). It emulates the user agent as well.

We were working with SAP's OpenUI5 UI application and Google Chrome's dev tools emulates very close iPhone experience. Much better than the iPhone emulator apps available online.